# Pervasive ODBC SQL Functions

Tags: sql, odbc, pervasive

I'm limited to using an ODBC connection to a Sage Mas 200 Pervasive DB.
Simply need to bring a decimal down as formatted currency... but not having any luck doing simple Transact SQL functions like ROUND(mydecimalfield,2) or even LEFT(myfield,4).

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What version of the ODBC driver are you using?  I'm using v11 and both of those functions  work correctly against the DEMODATA database.  Also, what exactly are the decimal fields defined as? Are you getting errors or incorrect values?

Comment: It's the version that came with client's Sage Mas. Looks like v4. Where can I found an updated odbc version?

Comment: v4?  What's the version of W3ODBCEI.DLL or W3ODBCCI.DLL?  Do you know what version of Pervasive you're using?  WHat's the version of W3BTRV7.DLL?